# Success & failure block written in Objective C, showing error in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have made a success & failure block in objC and I am trying to use that function in swift. Getting error, I'm stuck on it please help me.

**Objective C :**

```
  -(void)registerAppWithSuccessBlock:(void (^)(id responseObject))success andFailureBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure{}
```

I am calling the same function in swift its showing error.

**Swift :**

```
  USSecService.sharedInstance().registerAppWithSuccessBlock({(responseObject : AnyObject) -> Void in{code}
    }, andFailureBlock: { (error : NSError) -> Void in  {code}
  })
```

**Getting this Error :**

```
   Cannot invoke 'registerAppWithSuccessBlock' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject) -> Void, andFailureBlock: (NSError) -> Void)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
USSecService.sharedInstance().registerAppWithSuccessBlock({ (responseObject) -> Void in
        print("Success")
    }, andFailureBlock: { (error) -> Void in
        print("Failure")
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the argument type in those closures. Change your swift code like below:

**Without second closure label syntax:**

```
USSecService.sharedInstance().registerAppWithSuccessBlock({ (responseObject) -> Void in
     // Your success code
  }){ (error) -> Void in
     // Your error code
}
```

or

**With second closure label syntax:**

```
USSecService.sharedInstance().registerAppWithSuccessBlock({ (responseObject) -> Void in
    // Your success code
 }, andFailureBlock: ({ (error) -> Void in
    // Your error code 
 }))
```